# How can get node child tag from xml with dom (Java)

Tags: java, xml, dom, xstream

Took a long time searching and watching videos.
I'm trying to access the course subjects ID

This is my xml code

```
<list>
  <Asignatura>
    <id>1</id>
    <nombre>Programación</nombre>
    <curso>
      <id>1</id>
      <nombre>1º DAM</nombre>
      <listaAsignaturas>
        <Asignatura reference="../../.."/>
        <Asignatura>
          <id>2</id>
          <nombre>Bases de datos</nombre>
          <curso reference="../../.."/>
          <listaAlumnos/>
        </Asignatura>
        <Asignatura>
          <id>3</id>
          <nombre>Formación y orientación laboral</nombre>
          <curso reference="../../.."/>
          <listaAlumnos/>
        </Asignatura>
        <Asignatura>
          <id>4</id>
          <nombre>Entornos de desarrollo</nombre>
          <curso reference="../../.."/>
          <listaAlumnos/>
        </Asignatura>
      </listaAsignaturas>
    </curso>
    <listaAlumnos/>
  </Asignatura>
</list>
```

And here my code in java

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse("./datos/Asignaturas.xml");
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList Asignatura = document.getElementsByTagName("Asignatura");
    for (int i = 0; i < Asignatura.getLength(); i++) {
        Node c = Asignatura.item(i);
        if (c.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element elemento = (Element) c;

            int id = Integer.parseInt(getValorHijo("id", elemento));
            String nombre = getValorHijo("nombre", elemento);

            //int idCurso = Integer.parseInt(getValorHijo("curso", elemento));

            curso = new Curso();
            curso.setId(idCurso);
            curso = (Curso) FileXMLDAOFactory.getInstance().getCursoDAO().buscar(curso);

        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have to say it works, pick up the ID and name of the subject.
But I can not pick up the ID or name of the course subject that is within.

Im not have idea how can get it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a slighty different approach with the same xml input file with the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Assignatura> assignaturas = new ArrayList<Assignatura>();
        List<Curso> cursos = new ArrayList<Curso>();

        try{

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder loader = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = loader.parse("datos.xml");

        DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) document;

        NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(   
        document.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, new ListAsignaturasFilter(), true);

        for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {

            Element el = (Element) n;

            NodeList assignments = el.getElementsByTagName("Asignatura");

            for(int i=0; i<assignments.getLength(); i++){
                Node currentNode = assignments.item(i);
                NodeList childs = currentNode.getChildNodes();                  
                String id = getValorHijo(childs, "id");
                String nombre = getValorHijo(childs, "nombre");

                if(!id.isEmpty() || !nombre.isEmpty())
                    assignaturas.add(new Assignatura(id, nombre));          

            }       
        }

        NodeIterator itCurso = traversal.createNodeIterator(    
                document.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, new CursoFilter(), true);

        for (Node n = itCurso.nextNode(); n != null; n = itCurso.nextNode()) {

            Element el = (Element) n;

            NodeList cursos = el.getChildNodes();

            String id = getValorHijo(cursos, "id");
            String nombre = getValorHijo(cursos, "nombre");

            if(!id.isEmpty() || !nombre.isEmpty())
                cursos.add(new Curso(id, nombre));
        } 

        for(Assignatura assignatura : assignaturas){
            System.out.println(assignatura);
        }

        for(Curso curso : cursos){
            System.out.println(curso);
        }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   

    private static String getValorHijo(NodeList childs, String data){

        String search="";       

        if(childs.getLength()>0)

            for(int j=0; j<childs.getLength(); j++){
                if(childs.item(j).getNodeName().equals(data)){
                    return childs.item(j).getTextContent();
                }
            }

        return search;      
    }

    private static final class ListAsignaturasFilter implements NodeFilter {
        public short acceptNode(Node n) {
          if (n instanceof Element) {
            if (((Element) n).getTagName().equals("listaAsignaturas")) {
              return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            }
          }
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        }
      }

    private static final class CursoFilter implements NodeFilter {
        public short acceptNode(Node n) {
          if (n instanceof Element) {
            if (((Element) n).getTagName().equals("curso")) {
              return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            }
          }
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        }
      }
```

As you can see I created two lists to memorize "Assignatura" an "Curso" object which are simple POJO with two attributes id and nombre. At the end of the main method I display the content of these lists and I've got the id and nombre information of element "Curso" besides all "Asignatura" elements. Hope this code help you !

Just for the record. The use of DOM was compulsory ? Because, it would have been easier to use JAXB.